# Is it possible write linux kernel in Java Programming Language?

Tags: kernel, java

When linux kernel written in C so is it possible to write in java programming language, microkernel and monolithic kernel ?
Concern developing java os.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an overly-broad systems programming question.

Comment: It might be interesting for you to look at [Modula-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula-2) which was used to write the OS for the [Lilith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith_(computer)) workstation, and [Oberon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberon_(programming_language)) used for the eponymous OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C programs which get compiled in machine language, Java programs rely on a Java runtime engine which in turn relies on an existing system (including the kernel).

Even if it was conceptually possible to organize everything to get Java code to be run by the kernel, it would be inefficient and would probably require modifications of the Java engine.